# Tally instance running mode

Tags: tally

I am using vb.net to connect to Tally Erp9. Using xml requests I am exporting information from tally. But before exporting I would like to know in which mode the connected tally instance is running.
I would like to know if the tally is running in licensed or educational mode.

Is there any xml/TDL request that can be used to get the information?
Is it possible to get information about connected tally running in which mode?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Default Report in Tally that exposes license Info,
So we need to create it using TDL

Using below xml you can get license info and some other info from tally

This xml creates custom object which contains license info

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
    <ID>LicenseInfo</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <DESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES />
        <TDL>
            <TDLMESSAGE>
                <OBJECT NAME="LicenseInfo">
                    <LOCALFORMULA>IsEducationalMode:  $$LicenseInfo:IsEducationalMode</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>IsSilver: $$LicenseInfo:IsSilver</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>IsGold: $$LicenseInfo:IsGold</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>PlanName: If $$LicenseInfo:IsEducationalMode Then "Educational Version" ELSE  If $$LicenseInfo:IsSilver Then "Silver" ELSE  If $$LicenseInfo:IsGold Then "Gold" else ""</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>SerialNumber: $$LicenseInfo:SerialNumber</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>AccountId:$$LicenseInfo:AccountID</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>IsIndian: $$LicenseInfo:IsIndian</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>RemoteSerialNumber: $$LicenseInfo:RemoteSerialNumber</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>IsRemoteAccessMode: $$LicenseInfo:IsRemoteAccessMode</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>IsLicClientMode: $$LicenseInfo:IsLicClientMode</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>AdminMailId:$$LicenseInfo:AdminEmailID</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>IsAdmin:$$LicenseInfo:IsAdmin</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>ApplicationPath:$$SysInfo:ApplicationPath</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>DataPath:##SVCurrentPath</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>UserName:$$cmpusername</LOCALFORMULA>
                    <LOCALFORMULA>UserLevel:$$cmpuserlevel</LOCALFORMULA>
                </OBJECT>
                <COLLECTION NAME="LicenseInfo">
                    <OBJECTS>LicenseInfo</OBJECTS>
                </COLLECTION>
            </TDLMESSAGE>
        </TDL>
    </DESC>
</BODY>
```

You can find more xmls here - https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/13855108/TzeRpAMt

Answer (score 0):

you can create a tdl to extract license number. which will determine if tally is running in licensed mode else, it is in educational mode.